# Is there a way to disable logging / backups for view indexes?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, backup, materialized-view

We have a SQL Server database that uses indexed views to allow for efficient querying of some data that changes regularly (yes I know there's a cost to maintaining the index when the data changes but in our case it is *very* worth it).

My understanding is that changes to view indexes must be logged / backed up just like changes to any other table/index. However, it seems to me that such logging is redundant since SQL could easily rebuild the view index from the view definition in the event of a crash.

Is there any way to achieve something like this with SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### nope

There has been a long-standing request for SQL Server to support [unlogged objects](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/8cb77be4-7f25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0). It is available in varying forms in other database systems, both for tables and for materialized views.

However, as of this writing, you can't *choose* to mark an object of any variety as unlogged in SQL Server. While it may be logically redundant, it's unclear from your question if it's causing a problem or if you just don't like it and would prefer different behavior.

If you're experiencing performance issues with indexed view maintenance, you may want to [ask a more direct question about improving that](https://erikdarlingdata.com/indexed-view-maintenance-is-only-as-bad-as-your-indexes/) rather than looking for a change in current product behavior.

For your concerns around recovery (whether from crashes or reboots), you could take advantage of [Accelerated Database Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts?view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server 2019 and up.

Answer (score 4):

> My understanding is that changes to view indexes must be logged / backed up just like changes to any other table/index.

The logging ensures consistency in your database. A change made to an underlying table may not have finished writing to the index of the indexed view in the middle of a crash. Or perhaps even worse, if it was in the middle of rolling back the change during the crash.

> However, it seems to me that such logging is redundant since SQL could easily rebuild the view index from the view definition in the event of a crash.

*Easily* is subjective to begin with. If your indexed view is computationally heavy, it's probably easier, quicker, and less troublesome to your server to *pick up where it left off* based on the log. Also, there may be cases where data loss would occur if it didn't have the log to reference in the middle of a crash, especially since the results of the indexed view almost certainly don't match those of the underlying table(s).

> Is there any way to achieve something like this with SQL Server?

No, I don't believe so. But someone smarter than me may have a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

*Any* start-up and failover means that recovery is performed. Anything committed should be persisted, everything not-committed needs to be rolled back.

Having stuff excluded from this process would mean that most restarts/failovers would render your indexed views non-trusted (not only because of incorrect user-data, but also pointers going haywire etc).

Methinks that implementing what you ask for is a huge undertaking for Microsoft, possibly requiring a major redesign of the core of the database engine. – [user151544](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi)

---

Bear in mind that logging isn't needed only for *crash* recovery.

In a traditional [ARIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics) setup, log REDO information is needed to apply the effects of committed transactions to any database pages that had not been updated and flushed to stable storage as of the recovery point. Log UNDO information is needed to undo the effects of transactions that had made changes but were never committed according to the log.

The UNDO information is also needed to undo the effects of aborted transactions (due to a 'rollback' or error) during normal database operations.

If you don't log UNDO information, recovering from an ordinary error during data changes might require rebuilding the view and its indexes *after* the object(s) it references have been recovered. That might not be very popular.

As mentioned in another answer, the ARIES ideas are implemented differently under [*Accelerated Database Recovery*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts#the-accelerated-database-recovery-process) (ADR). Log records still need to be written as before but REDO is much, much faster and UNDO almost instantaneous (though background clean up continues separately).

Since the same log records are written, ADR doesn't appear to meet the stated goals—but the performance improvements and reduced active log size might. That said, ADR does have overhead and isn't applied for short transactions, so you can't get away from traditional UNDO processing completely.

Answer (score 2):

There would be nothing to stop the SQL Server team from implementing a `WITH NOINDEXES` option for backups, and then rebuilding them from the clustered indexes. In other words: the same arguments you use for indexed views also apply to non-clustered indexes.

But the fact remains that they have not done so. It's an all or nothing backup process. To wit: you can't even do a per-table backup. This has been requested for many years already, and is now the [**third-highest voted request on the feedback site**](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e4c0c9e0-6425-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0), and I strongly recommend you also vote for it.